# Windows 8.1 XAML - LayoutTransform

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, custom-controls, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to use the LayoutTransform property to rotate some text 90 degrees in a windows 8.1/VS2013 template.

I am aware LayoutTransform is not in WinRT XAML so I followed the instructions on igrali's [blog](http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/) for using Layout transform in Windows 8 WinRT XAML but visual studio keeps saying:

> 'The name Layout Transformer" does not exist in the namespace
>   "using:Transforming.Common.'

Is this because I need to do something differently due to the changes in windows 8.1?

Joe

Comment: Your title refers to LayoutTransform but the error message says "LayoutTransformer" with an -er. Do you have a typo?

Comment: LayoutTransform is the name of the class that I downloaded from http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/ . In this class is a method called LayoutTransform that I'm trying to use from my XAML code so I can set the LayoutTransform property to an element.

Comment: Have you included the class Igor wrote about in your project?

Comment: Yeah and i was trying to link to that in my XAML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I found out how to do it eventually. I just had to make sure I had the correct name spaces above the style in app.xaml and mainpage.xaml. I just copied the namespace for common already included in the template into app.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Sample Text">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for LayoutTransform as RenderTransform does not give the element it's own space and retains the width. There is a good explanation here http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/